# Condition that only posts author can see secret contents

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am trying to display a message if the user that logged in is the author of the post. I put this inside `have_post()` loop to display on each of every `index.php` posts but I don't think this caused the problem. I have tried 2 ways:

```
<?php
 if ( is_author( get_the_author_meta('ID') ) ) {
  echo "You are the author of this post";
 }
 else
  {
 echo "You are NOT the author of this post";
  }
?>
```

And this

```
<?php
 if ($getid == $current_user->ID) {
  echo "You are the author of this post";
 }
 else
  {
 echo "You are NOT the author of this post";
  }
?>
```

Both of them return me the else statement although I am testing on my local host and using my account (which is the only account). Somehow I feel like I did wrong somewhere. Any ideas?

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4xOQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<?php
 if ( get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta('ID') ) {
  echo "You are the author of this post";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "You are NOT the author of this post";
 }
?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to modify the author.php page, this piece of code will probably work :

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) {
    edit_post_link('edit', '', '');
    // Or any of your code
}
```

The first part of the conditions checks if there is a user logged. The second one will be true if the current page is the author page of the current user.

Or other work around is

```
global $post, $current_user;

if($post->post_author == $current_user->ID)  { 
    // show edit link  
    // or any of your custom code  
}
```

These are not tested by myself but i guess it will get your job done :)